# Set ACL for Google Storage Object with JSON Api in Appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I would like to ADD a ACL to a Google Storage object using the Json API from appengine.  I have tried the following code, however I get a 400 response with no details. I am not using the java-client-libraries, however I am willing to try.  Below is my code:

```
public static void updateACL(String bucket, String object,
        List<String> emails) {

    try {
        ArrayList scopes = new ArrayList();
        scopes.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control");
        AppIdentityService appIdentity = AppIdentityServiceFactory
                .getAppIdentityService();
        AppIdentityService.GetAccessTokenResult accessToken = appIdentity
                .getAccessToken(scopes);
        // The token asserts the identity reported by
        // appIdentity.getServiceAccountName()
        logger.log(Level.WARNING, "bucket: "+bucket+" object: "+object+ " email: "+emails.get(0));
        JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
        request.put("entity", "user-" + emails.get(0));
        request.put("roles", "READER");

        URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1beta1/b/"
                + bucket + "/o/"+object+"/acl?key=" + API_KEY);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "OAuth "
                + accessToken.getAccessToken());
        String urlParameters = "bucket=" + bucket + "&object=" + object;
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
                connection.getOutputStream());
        request.write(writer);
        writer.close();
        logger.log(Level.WARNING, connection.getResponseMessage());
        logger.log(Level.WARNING,
                String.valueOf(connection.getResponseCode()));
        if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            // Note: Should check the content-encoding.
            // JSONTokener response_tokens = new
            // JSONTokener(connection.getInputStream());
            // JSONObject response = new JSONObject(response_tokens);
            // return (String) response.get("id");
            return;
        } else {

        Scanner s;
        s = new Scanner(connection.getErrorStream());
        s.useDelimiter("\\Z");
        String response = s.next();
        s.close();
            throw new Exception(connection.getResponseCode()+" "+connection.getResponseMessage()+
                    response);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        logger.log(Level.WARNING, "exception: "+e.getMessage());

    }
}
```

The response I get is a 400, but the details are not helpful at all.

> "error": {
>     "errors": [
>      {
>       "domain": "global",
>       "reason": "required",
>       "message": "Required"
>      }
>     ],
>     "code": 400,
>     "message": "Required"
>    }
>   }

Comment: Try changing roles to role in request.put("roles", "READER")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect there's a tiny bug or two in your code. In this particular instance it looks like you are sending roles when the JSON api expects role.

One thing I find helpful for debugging is to compare what my code is sending over the wire with the HTTP request the [Google APIs explorer](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/) generates.

1. Navigate to https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objectAccessControls/insert
2. Turn on the `Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0` button.
3. Set the `bucket`, `object`, `entity` and `role` fields.
4. Click execute.

You should see the resulting HTTP request and response.

Request:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1beta1/b/bucket/o/obj/acl?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer ya29.1111111111111111111111111111111111-aaaaaaaaaaaaa
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{
 "entity": "user-person@example.com",
 "role": "READER"
}
```

Response:

```
200 OK

- Hide headers -

cache-control:  no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:  Fri, 30 Nov 2012 02:16:57 GMT
etag:  "fP_WVz7o95h5w16zKezUFJzMmHg/6CyL8wOk_60IJhaxNewPk1fHpQo"
expires:  Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
server:  GSE

{

 "kind": "storage#objectAccessControl",
 "id": "bucket/obj/user-person@example.com",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1beta1/b/bucket/o/obj/acl/user-person@example.com",
 "bucket": "bucket",
 "object": "obj",
 "entity": "user-person@example.com",
 "role": "READER",
 "email": "person@example.com"
}
```

Now make sure the request you are sending over the wire looks the same as this one.